# Jquery Grep & Map Json Using Multiple Keywords

Tags: jquery, json, search, filter

I want to filter and search through Json using multiple keywords. I have it working when there is only one value to check against, but I need to use multiple keyword search filters.

In this example, I want to return the objects related to Wal-mart and China but NOT Wal-Mart in the US or Target in China.

I create an array of keywords to filter using Grep() and Map that out in console. I cannot figure out the syntax to check the value against the keyword however (see my comment below, "This is not right.")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>

var keywords = ["China", "Wal-Mart"];//filter Json by these terms

var data = [
    {
    "name": "Store #1",
    "country": "China",
    "retailer": "Wal-Mart"
    },
    {
    "name": "New Store #2",
    "country": "China",
    "retailer": "Wal-Mart"
    },
    {
    "name": "Store Name US",
    "country": "United States",
    "retailer": "Wal-Mart"
    },
    {
    "name": "Target #98237",
    "country": "China",
    "retailer": "Target"
    }
]
var searchkeywords = $.grep(data, function(value,i) { 

return value[i] === keywords[i];//<--- This is not right

//should be the equivalent of above keywords:
//return value.country.toLowerCase() === "china" && value.retailer.toLowerCase() === "wal-mart" 
});

var keywordsearchresult = $.map(searchkeywords, function(value, i) {
    return {
        name: value.name,
        country: value.country,
        retailer: value.retailer
    };
});
console.log(keywordsearchresult);//should return first 2 items
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In my application, there will be more keywords and items (type, date, etc..) in the Json, this is just a simplified version. I basically want to add a lot of rules and conditions to the Grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is that your search terms give no indication of which field they are supposed to be filtering on.  I would change the format of your terms to this:

```
var keywords = [
    {
        field: "country",
        value: "China"
    },
    {
        field: "retailer",
        value: "Wal-Mart"
    }
];
```

This allows your search to search the appropriate fields for each word.  Then you can change your grep to this:

```
var results = $.grep(data, function(value, i) {
    for(var i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
        if(value[keywords[i].field] !== keywords[i].value){
            return false   
        }
    }

    return true;        
});
```

I have removed the `map` part because I can't see any use for it.  Then you are left with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kZWef/

Comment: Thanks! I was using map to render a html template. But I can instead just use results as a var object to populate instead.

Comment: How would I search on two keywords using country? For example if I wanted to return where country = United States OR China var keywords = [
    {
        field: "country",
        value: "China"
    },
 {
        field: "country",
        value: "United States"
    }
];

Comment: You could makes the `value` an array  `{field: "country", value: ["China", "United States"]}`.

Comment: Yes, you would have to loop through the `value` array.  But you could not simply return false if one doesn't match, you would have to check that the value does not match any of the values, then return false.

Comment: Actually, if you're using jquery you can just use `inArray`.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/